# How can I import a python module from a relative directory in VSCode?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, import

I am using VSCode editor and getting an error while importing a module from a sub-directory that is inside the same parent directory as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Test\Packages\MyPackage\B\b.py", line 2, in <module>
    import MyPackage.A.a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyPackage'
```

As you can also see I have `__init__.py` in every directory which is just a 0 bytes file to tell python that the directory is a package.

I was able to solve this using the following line:

```
sys.path.append("D:/Test/Packages")
```

I heard there's a better way to do it. Is there another but better way to do it?

Comment: you heard wrong ... use the path ... but you could just `sys.path.append("..")` if its always the parent ... or run it from the D:\Test\Packages folder (`cd D:\Test\Packages;  python MyPackage/B/b.py`)

Comment: from ..A import a (using relative imports) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: For example `python -m MyPackage.B.b`, is that not what I need to configure in VSCode in order to do it another way?

Comment: Did you try import Package.MyPackage.A.a?

Comment: Yes, that gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Packages'`.

Comment: afaik you cannot use relative imports in an entry point script? @frab (I could be wrong ... i know in py2 that was true)

Comment: @frab: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` that's an error.

Comment: Ever heard of "pip editable installs", the pythonic way to solve the issue?